# How do I remap keys in caret mode and textarea mode in vimperator?

Tags: keyboard-layout, firefox-extensions, remapping, vimperator

I use vimperator with my operating system set to an alternate keyboard layout. It's pretty easy to remap things in insert and normal mode with `inoremap` and `nnoremap` in my `.vimperatorrc`, but I can't find how to remap keys in caret mode or textarea mode. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, it may be useful for you to know that Pentadactyl – further development of Vimperator – allows you to remap keys in caret and textarea modes easily with `:map -modes caret,text-edit` or even `:map -modes command` if you want the same mappings for normal, visual, caret and text-edit modes.

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to this. If you want fine-grained control over your mappings Pentadactyl is absolutely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: If you want to do advanced customizations like this, you'll have a *much* easier time if you use [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/) instead of Vimperator. Leaving this here for completeness.

---

You will need to edit the source code of Vimperator itself, but it really isn't terrible.
Here's what you need to do:

1. find the xpi file for vimperator

   Firefox stores the code for its extensions in `.xpi` files, which are basically zip files containing the code for the add on. The easiest way to find the vimperator xpi is by installing the super-tiny add-on [open profile folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-profile-folder/), press <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to open the tools menu, choose "open profile folder", and navigate to the subdirectory `extensions`. Here you'll find the xpi files for all your addons; look for the one with "vimperator" in the name. For me, its `vimperator@mozdev.org.xpi`.

   If you have a good search tool like [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) or Spotlight on Mac, you can probably just search for "vimperator" and look for files with the `.xpi` extension.
2. Copy the xpi file to your Desktop and change the extension from `.xpi` to `.zip`
3. Open the zip archive and navigate to `common/content/`. Open the file `editor.js` in a text editor
4. Search for "addMovementMap"

   You should find something like this:

   ```
   //             KEYS                          COUNT  CARET                   TEXTAREA            VISUAL_TEXTAREA
   addMovementMap(["k", "<Up>"],                true,  "lineMove", false,      "cmd_linePrevious", selectPreviousLine);
   addMovementMap(["j", "<Down>", "<Return>"],  true,  "lineMove", true,       "cmd_lineNext",     selectNextLine);
   addMovementMap(["h", "<Left>", "<BS>"],      true,  "characterMove", false, "cmd_charPrevious", "cmd_selectCharPrevious");
   addMovementMap(["l", "<Right>", "<Space>"],  true,  "characterMove", true,  "cmd_charNext",     "cmd_selectCharNext");
   addMovementMap(["b", "B", "<C-Left>"],       true,  "wordMove", false,      "cmd_wordPrevious", "cmd_selectWordPrevious");
   addMovementMap(["w", "W", "e", "<C-Right>"], true,  "wordMove", true,       "cmd_wordNext",     "cmd_selectWordNext");
   addMovementMap(["<C-f>", "<PageDown>"],      true,  "pageMove", true,       "cmd_movePageDown", "cmd_selectNextPage");
   addMovementMap(["<C-b>", "<PageUp>"],        true,  "pageMove", false,      "cmd_movePageUp",   "cmd_selectPreviousPage");
   addMovementMap(["gg", "<C-Home>"],           false, "completeMove", false,  "cmd_moveTop",      "cmd_selectTop");
   addMovementMap(["G", "<C-End>"],             false, "completeMove", true,   "cmd_moveBottom",   "cmd_selectBottom");
   addMovementMap(["0", "^", "<Home>"],         false, "intraLineMove", false, "cmd_beginLine",    "cmd_selectBeginLine");
   addMovementMap(["$", "<End>"],               false, "intraLineMove", true,  "cmd_endLine" ,     "cmd_selectEndLine" );
   ```

   The letters in quotes are the mappings for caret mode and textarea mode. Change them to whatever you want and save the file. Use `<C-f>` to map a function to <kbd>Control f</kbd>
5. Go into firefox and uninstall vimperator. This will get rid of the old xpi so you can use the one we just edited
6. Change the extension of the zip file back to xpi
7. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> in firefox, navigate to the new xpi on your desktop, and select open. Firefox will install it as a new add on.
8. Restart Firefox and enjoy the new bindings!

One issue is that if you update vimperator, you will need to do this again with the new xpi, but you should be able to just replace this section in the new version with your edited version from the old one.